# Java 8 streams is taking more time than usual loop, in reading a file and to find a word count

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was just trying how the performance of Java 8 streams would be comparatively using legacy way of file parsing using LinenumberReader. And to my surprise, the legacy code is considerably faster than the Streams. The logic for parsing is the same for both. Any idea why this is so ?

Below are the two methods, one for streams and other for regular Filereader/Linenumberreader.

```
private static void streamWalkthrough(Stream<String> lines) {
        long startTime=new Date().getTime();
        AtomicLong atomicLong=new AtomicLong();
        lines.map(eachLine-> {
            return eachLine.split(" ");
        }).forEach(lineArray->{
            Long occurenceOnEachLine=Arrays.stream(lineArray).filter(eachWord->{
                if(eachWord.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Kafka")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).count();
            if(occurenceOnEachLine>0) {
                long existingLongValue=atomicLong.get();
                atomicLong.set(existingLongValue+occurenceOnEachLine);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Stream code took : "+(new Date().getTime()-startTime));
    }
    private static void legacyWalkthrough() {
     try {
        LineNumberReader reader=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line="";
        int wordCount=0;
        long startTime=new Date().getTime();
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
            String str[]=line.split(" ");
            for (String word : str) {
                if(word.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("kafka")) {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Legacy code took : "+(new Date().getTime()-startTime));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide inputs you tested with and your results? Were the results reproducible on different machines? Did you run the tests in a loop and average the times? --- I would strongly recomment to use `System.nanoTime()` to calculate the elapsed time. --- I would also recommend to use [jmh](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: change stream version to this: `lines.map(l->l.split(" "))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .filter(w->w.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("kafka")).count();`

Comment: You can change the stream like `lines.flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.split(" "))).filter(e -> e.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Kafka")).count();` avoiding `AtomicLong`

Comment: Also consider substring match count on line rather spliting and check equal. And you  can use `parallelStream()` in your case I think

Comment: The below as suggested by @Rono is faster. Can you explain what does this flatMap() does ?
lines.map(l->l.split(" ")).
  flatMap(Arrays::stream).
  filter(w->w.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("kafka")).
  count();

Comment: @Hirein In your case, it flattens the words of every line so that streams contains a list of words only. You  can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/)

Comment: @Rono Even in the doc (as well as in the link you shared) it says it flattens. But what exactly it flattens ?

Comment: Flatten means replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function `Stream<String>`(lines) -> `Stream<String[]>`(lines of words) -> `Stream<String>`(words)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Rono the below code worked for me. It is efficient than the usual Readers..

```
lines.map(l->l.split(" ")). flatMap(Arrays::stream). filter(w->w.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("kafka")). count();
```

Comment: Acctually the version of code suggested by [Hadi J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j) not me

Comment: or simpler: `lines.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream) .filter("kafka"::equalsIgnoreCase).count()`